# BroadCastReceiver Method getDebugUnregister();

Tags: android

kindly Explain the working to `getDebugUnregister();` and how to use this in

> BroadcastReceiver();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returns the last value given to

```
setDebugUnregister(boolean);
```